# Azure Pipelines Powershell task to manipulate Excel data on Self-Hosted agent

Tags: excel, powershell, azure-devops

I have Pipeline where I am running Powershell task to manipulate excel data on self-hosted agent. Agent is running with my account - administrator.

When I run script locally on that machine, it works completely fine, but when I run it in pipelines, it shows successful, but it seems that it cannot save changes performed on excel file.
So I need to open excel sheet, check data based on one column, update some data, add new data and close excel. Then I copy that excel to one-drive folder on machine.

It should be quite simple, but ended up as a pain in the neck for me. Any help is very welcome!

Comment: Are you using excel automation (COM)? In that case, it causes a lot of issues when your agent isn't running interactively. A package like NPOI (https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi) to edit the file from your PowerShell script. That won't need to run Excel in the background and is much safer for unattended automation.

Comment: See also: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2